# Print Min/Max of each Columns of a DataFrame using a "for loop" in a "function

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, func

I know this maybe a stupid question but I am stuck:

```
df=[column names such as "Water", "Soil", "Fire"]
report=[]

def area():
   for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
       max_col(i)= df[col].max()
       min_col(i)= df[col].min()
       balance(i)= max_col(i) + min_col(i)

       print(-------,col,------) # column name
       print(max_col(i))
       print(min_col(i))
       print(balance_col(i))

   return pd.DataFrame(report)
```

I get this error: `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`
I want to `display(print)` the calculated values for each column separately, and return the results through a new df. Many thanks

Comment: can you add some data?

Comment: What are `max_col`, `min_col`, and `balance`? Are they functions? If so, then can you explain what you're trying to do, because like the error message says, you can't assign a value to the result of a function call.

Comment: No, they are just minimum and maximum values of each columns. They are float or integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dictionaries to store the values for `min_col`, `max_col` and `balance`, each one keyed on the column name.  Then combine the results into the `result` dataframe.

```
def area(df):
    min_col = {}
    max_col = {}
    balance = {}
    for col in df:
        max_col[col]= df[col].max()
        min_col[col]= df[col].min()
        balance[col]= max_col[col] + min_col[col]

    result = pd.DataFrame([min_col, max_col, balance], index=['min', 'max', 'balance'])
    return result

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
>>> df
          A         B         C
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863

>>> area(df)
                A         B         C
min      0.410599 -0.151357 -0.977278
max      2.240893  1.867558  1.454274
balance  2.651492  1.716201  0.476996
```

You can get the same result with the following:

```
df.apply(lambda s: pd.Series([s.min(), s.max(), s.max() + s.min()], 
                              index=['min', 'max', 'balance'])
)
```

Comment: no need for dictionaries IMO. My answer builds on top of OP code and does the job

Answer (score -1):

### Use this:

```
# fake data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 1], [4, 5, 6,4], [7, 8, 9, 6]]),
                             columns=['a', 'b', 'c','d'])

def area(df):
   # define the output dataframe
   df_out= pd.DataFrame(columns=['col_name','max','min','balance'])
   for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
       report=[]
       max_col= df[col].max()
       min_col= df[col].min()
       balance= max_col + min_col
       report.append(col) # column name
       report.append(max_col)
       report.append(min_col)
       report.append(balance)  
       df_out.loc[i] = report
   return df_out

area(df)
```

Output:

```
  col_name max min balance
0        a   7   1       8
1        b   8   2      10
2        c   9   3      12
3        d   6   1       7
```

Comment: Thanks you. But you have never used i in your code!

Comment: see my updated answer. the other answer seems too much complicated to this simple task

Comment: Thank you makis.